# JAXB SchemaGen with Enums in a different package

Tags: xsd, jaxb, schemagen

How do you generate a schema from JAXB Objects that reference enums in a different package?

Below is an example:

Enum Class

```
package com.example.one

public enum EnumExample {
    VALUE_ONE
    VALUE_TWO
}
```

JAXB Class

```
package com.example.two

public class Example {

private EnumExample enumExample;

    @XMLElement(name="enumExample", required=true)
    public EnumExample getEnumExample() {
        return enumExample
    }

    public void setEnumExample() {
        this.enumExample = enumExample;
    }
}
```

package-info.java

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://example.com", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED) 
package com.example.two;
```

Ant Target

```
<path id="glassfish.schemagen.classpath">
    <pathelement location="/apps/glassfish/lib/webservices-tools.jar" />
</path>

<taskdef name="schemagen" classname="com.sun.tools.jxc.SchemaGenTask">
    <classpath refid="glassfish.schemagen.classpath" />
</taskdef>

<schemagen srcdir="${src.dir}/com/example/two" destdir="xsd">
    <schema namespace="http://exmaple.com" file="example.xsd" />
</schemagen>
```

When I run the above example I get the following:

> [schemagen] anomalous package-info.java path: package-info.java
>   [schemagen] Generating schema from 7 source files
>   [schemagen] Problem encountered during annotation processing; 
>   [schemagen] see stacktrace below for more information.
>   [schemagen] java.lang.NullPointerException
>   [schemagen]     at com.sun.tools.jxc.model.nav.APTNavigator$2.onDeclaredType(APTNavigator.java:428)
>   [schemagen]     at com.sun.tools.jxc.model.nav.APTNavigator$2.onClassType(APTNavigator.java:402)
>   [schemagen]     at com.sun.tools.jxc.model.nav.APTNavigator$2.onClassType(APTNavigator.java:456)
>   [schemagen]     at com.sun.istack.tools.APTTypeVisitor.apply(APTTypeVisitor.java:27)
>   [schemagen]     at com.sun.tools.jxc.model.nav.APTNavigator.getBaseClass(APTNavigator.java:109)
>   [schemagen]     at com.sun.tools.jxc.model.nav.APTNavigator.getBaseClass(APTNavigator.java:85)
>   [schemagen]     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.PropertyInfoImpl.getIndividualType(PropertyInfoImpl.java:190)
>   [schemagen]     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.PropertyInfoImpl.(PropertyInfoImpl.java:132)
>   [schemagen]     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ERPropertyInfoImpl.(ERPropertyInfoImpl.java:53)
>   [schemagen]     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl.(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:96)
>   [schemagen]     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.createElementProperty(ClassInfoImpl.java:886)
>   [schemagen]     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.addProperty(ClassInfoImpl.java:841)
>   [schemagen]     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.findGetterSetterProperties(ClassInfoImpl.java:966)
>   [schemagen]     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ClassInfoImpl.getProperties(ClassInfoImpl.java:298)
>   [schemagen]     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:243)
>   [schemagen]     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:209)
>   [schemagen]     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:315)
>   [schemagen]     at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:330)
>   [schemagen]     at com.sun.tools.xjc.api.impl.j2s.JavaCompilerImpl.bind(JavaCompilerImpl.java:90)
>   [schemagen]     at com.sun.tools.jxc.apt.SchemaGenerator$1.process(SchemaGenerator.java:115)
>   [schemagen]     at com.sun.mirror.apt.AnnotationProcessors$CompositeAnnotationProcessor.process(AnnotationProcessors.java:60)
>   [schemagen]     at com.sun.tools.apt.comp.Apt.main(Apt.java:454)
>   [schemagen]     at com.sun.tools.apt.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:258)
>   [schemagen]     at com.sun.tools.apt.main.Main.compile(Main.java:1102)
>   [schemagen]     at com.sun.tools.apt.main.Main.compile(Main.java:964)
>   [schemagen]     at com.sun.tools.apt.Main.processing(Main.java:95)
>   [schemagen]     at com.sun.tools.apt.Main.process(Main.java:85)
>   [schemagen]     at com.sun.tools.apt.Main.process(Main.java:67)
>   [schemagen]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   [schemagen]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   [schemagen]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   [schemagen]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>   [schemagen]     at com.sun.tools.jxc.AptBasedTask$InternalAptAdapter.execute(AptBasedTask.java:97)
>   [schemagen]     at com.sun.tools.jxc.AptBasedTask.compile(AptBasedTask.java:144)
>   [schemagen]     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:906)
>   [schemagen]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
>   [schemagen]     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
>   [schemagen]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   [schemagen]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>   [schemagen]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>   [schemagen]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
>   [schemagen]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
>   [schemagen]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
>   [schemagen]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1397)
>   [schemagen]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1366)
>   [schemagen]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
>   [schemagen]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1249)
>   [schemagen]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:801)
>   [schemagen]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:218)
>   [schemagen]     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
>   [schemagen]     at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)

I know it's the enum's causing the error because if I switch to a String it goes away. How can I generate a schema with the above example where the enums are either in the same namespace or a different name space?

Answer (score 0):

> [schemagen](http://jaxb.java.net/2.2.5/docs/ch04.html#tools-schemagen-ant-task) supports most of the attributes defined by the [javac task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html)

Have you tried using include or exclude elements (untested)?

```
<schemagen srcdir="${src.dir}/com/example" destdir="xsd">
    <schema namespace="http://exmaple.com" file="example.xsd" />
    <include name="one/EnumExample.java"/>
    <include name="two/Example.java"/>
</schemagen>
```